# How to get all visible local variable names within a scope with Roslyn (Microsoft CodeAnalysis)

Tags: c#, roslyn

(Please note: This is not about run-time reflection/metainfo)

I am writing a concrete implementation of Roslyn CSharpSyntaxVisitor

When implementing the VisitIdentifierName

```
public override SyntaxNode VisitIdentifierName(IdentifierNameSyntax name)
{
   var symbolInfo = _semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(name);
   var fieldSymbol = symbolInfo.Symbol as IFieldSymbol;
   if (fieldSymbol != null)
   {
       // Here I would like to get all the local variable names what are visible
       // in the very same scope where this field IdentifierNameSyntax under visiting resides
       // We can suppose that _semanticNodel for the Document is available.
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is ever possible. What you can do instead is defining anonymous variable which would contain all variables you have. Then you can navigate through all properties of that instance using reflection. e.g. var locals = new { symbolInfo, fieldSymbol,... }. then use locals.GetType().GetProperties()

Comment: Maybe I missed something but it seems to your answer is not about Roslyn SyntaxTree instead general reflection

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. Never mind

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call [`SemanticModel.LookupSymbols()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.semanticmodel.lookupsymbols?view=roslyn-dotnet#Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_SemanticModel_LookupSymbols_System_Int32_Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_INamespaceOrTypeSymbol_System_String_System_Boolean_) ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/1331a9d29a90798b0e7338e2829d7cd314960877/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/Compilation/SemanticModel.cs#L458)), then filter for local variables.

You may also want to filter out locals declared after that location; see [this code](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/1331a9d29a90798b0e7338e2829d7cd314960877/src/Workspaces/CSharp/Portable/Recommendations/CSharpRecommendationServiceRunner.cs#L239-L242).

Comment: You can call into the recommender directly with [this API](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Recommendations/Recommender.cs).

Comment: @JasonMalinowski: But that will do more work than he strictly needs.

Comment: Yes, but it's probably going to be less code them him re-filtering for the locals-after stuff.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski, SLaks: Thanks for you both this help. I did not even hope that such an agile and understanding supporters are there in this ezoteric topic :-).

Comment: Well, this is my job. :-)