# How to get the name of internal variables used in a method

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

How is it possible (maybe through Reflection or Roslyn APIs) to get the list of internal variables that are used in a class method?

For example, in the following code:

```
class C1{
   private int var1;
   public string var2;

   void action1()
    {
       int var3;
       var3=var1*var1;
       var2="Completed";
   }
}
```

I would like to get var3,var1 and var2 as the list(as name and type) of variables used in the action1() method.

Secondly, I need to identify which of the above variables appear on the left side of an expression; i.e., their values have been modified in this method.

I think the answer lies in using Roslyn, but I have no idea how. Thanks!

Comment: Through reflection you can't. During compilation time in non-debug mode, the name of the variables are removed.

Comment: Just to make sure, do you want to do it with source code *.cs file or compiled assembly *.dll file?

Comment: And Roslyn isn't usable to take a look at "running" code. It is to be used to analyze source code, or generate source code.

Comment: Why would you want to do this anyway? It seems like a very strange thing to do.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov with the source code. The goal is to do a DU (define-use) path analysis of variables. If I can extract the same information from the compiled version of the source, it would be fine as well.

Comment: @PJvG, to do a DU path analysis .

Comment: What should happen if you have more complicated code, like `this.someField = F(a.b.c);`?

Comment: @svick, really great point! In my context and analysis, I do not need to deal with such cases (yet), but for sure it can be necessary in some other contexts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @xanatos mentioned, it is not possible get this information from compiled assembly. You should use Roslyn for this task and have access to the source code. This answer explains how you can retrieve variables https://stackoverflow.com/a/23543883/2138959 and this article can be a good start [Getting Started C# Semantic Analysis](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-C%23-Semantic-Analysis).

Going through latter article you could came up with following code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

namespace Roslyn
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
class C1{
   private int var1;
   public string var2;

   void action1()
    {
       int var3;
       var3=var1*var1;
       var2=""Completed"";
   }
}
");
            var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax) tree.GetRoot();
            var variableDeclarations = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<VariableDeclarationSyntax>();

            Console.WriteLine("Declare variables:");

            foreach (var variableDeclaration in variableDeclarations)
                Console.WriteLine(variableDeclaration.Variables.First().Identifier.Value);

            var variableAssignments = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<AssignmentExpressionSyntax>();

            Console.WriteLine("Assign variables:");

            foreach (var variableAssignment in variableAssignments)
                Console.WriteLine($"Left: {variableAssignment.Left}, Right: {variableAssignment.Right}");
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces following output:

```
Declare variables:
var1
var2
var3
Assign variables:
Left: var3, Right: var1*var1
Left: var2, Right: "Completed"
```

Make sure to install [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/) NuGet package.

Comment: Thanks @Andrii, This much I had already suspected, e.g., that I need to use Roslyn, the question is how. Many of the Roslyn samples are not valid due to API changes etc. I had searched a lot on this before posting the question here.

Comment: @Supernova, okay, makes sense. I might spend some time tomorrow to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @Supernova, I have updated my answer with code example.

Comment: It worked like a charm @Andrii . Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: is it possible to get the list of declared variables per method name of a class? Or alternatively, get fully qualified name of variables? The goal is figure out which variables belong to which method and then which class.

Comment: @Supernova, you should be able to do it by traversing `root`. Try go through child nodes with debugger to see what is inside. When you find node for method that you can search for variables declared inside.